# ion-view height doesn't match content height

Tags: ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I experience an issue with nested views in my Ionic app. I have a custom tab 
navigation which is placed within my parent ion-view. The tab navigation is intended to scroll together with the content, which is located in an ion-nav-view underneath. For that I put the `scroll="false"` onto the child's ion-content.

**The problem is, that my content won't expand the parent's height to fit the content's height**. It has a height of 100%, which is fixed to the view's initial height. So at the end of the page there is content left, which is never displayed. Here is the template code (I am sorry, I cannot provide a plunkr example):

```
<ion-view>

    <ion-content on-swipe-left="tabs.goToNext()" on-swipe-right="tabs.goToPrevious()">
        <div class="tabbed-slidebox">
            <div class="tsb-icons">
                <div class="tsb-ic-wrp" style="">
                    <a href="#/app/claims/creation/step-what" ng-class="{active: tabs.activeTab === 'Was'}">Was</a>
                    <a href="#/app/claims/creation/step-who" ng-class="{active: tabs.activeTab === 'Wer'}">Wer</a>
                    <a href="#/app/claims/creation/step-where" ng-class="{active: tabs.activeTab === 'Wo'}">Wo</a>
                    <a href="#/app/claims/creation/step-when" ng-class="{active: tabs.activeTab === 'Wann'}">Wann</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <ion-nav-view name="stepContent">

            <!-- For illustration I copied ion-view from the template which will be rendered into this ion-nav-view -->
            <ion-view view-title="Schadenmeldung">
                <ion-content class="step step-what padding" scroll="false">
                    <!-- CONTENT -->
                </ion-content>
            </ion-view>

        </ion-nav-view>
    </ion-content>

    <div class="fab-sticky">
        <!-- some sticky button here -->
    </div>

</ion-view>
```

[See a demo here](https://i.imgsafe.org/fb449c2.gif)

My view hierarchy looks somehow like this:

- **app view** (mainly ion-nav-bar)

  - **tabs view** (mainly tab navigation)

    - **content view** (content intended to expand the ion-view's height)

(I can provide the state config if that helps)

I already played around with the CSS a lot. But since I am no CSS Mastermind, I did not find a solution. 
The problem seems to come from the `position: absolute` of the ion-nav-view. It prevents the height to 
adapt to the content.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

you can add style into ion-nav-view
for example：
`<ion-nav-view name="stepContent" style="height: 380px"></ion-nav-view>`